# Can SSMS QueryBuilder use multiple databases in Design View?

Tags: sql, ssms, query-builder

Can SSMS QueryBuilder somehow support multiple databases in Design View? How could they not let you select the database for the Add tables dialog?

These are even on the same server and same SQL Instance.

Is there something I'm missing with the Query Builder?

Is there another inexpensive UI friendly tool that allows building cross database queries? I want something easier for myself (C# developer not DBA) as well as the other not quite so techy folks around here to use.

Comment: Anyone know if this is possible with SSMS or some other inexpensive tool? Thx!

Comment: Eehh - a C# developer should be able to write queries without the query designer, and then you can just use the fully qualified `database.schema.table`

Comment: Able and always wanting to are two different things...

Answer (score 2):

You can't choose another database in the Add Table dialog, but the query designer has no problem with tables from multiple databases.  Just go to the FROM clause in the SQL pane and add ", database.schema.table" manually.  When you click in the Diagram pane the new table should pop up (as a CROSS JOIN).  You can then wire it to another table in the diagram pane to fill in the join clause.